# how to use indigo package in kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

rosprofiler package is available in indigo but not in kinetic. Can anybody let me know how to use the same in kinetic .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255820/how-to-use-indigo-package-in-kinetic/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can find source code for the package (for example on github) then you can clone the repository to your workspace and try to build it by yourself (using catkin_make) as you would normally do with any other package.

There is a risk that a package might have some dependencies on other packages that are not supported in Kinetic in which case you have to resolve them yourself.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) with karma: 311 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on 2017-03-05**:
Thanks .  Is it possible to get the rosprofiler  source code of  indigo version so that same i can build in kinetic version.

**Comment by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) on 2017-03-06**:
I'm guessing from the last commit date that this repository contains the source code for rosprofiler targeting indigo: https://github.com/osrf/rosprofiler